# Make a fixed div be covered up by content div as you scroll up

Tags: css, html

I have a fix dive with content at the top of my page and I would like to make the content cover up the fixed div at the top as you scroll up, but stay fixed to give that scrolling over the top effect but when I do so you can still see the fixed content over the content.

You can see the the issue happening at http://hearthable.com, when you scroll down the site you see the main logo is still visible but I would like it to be not be there once you scroll up past it.

```
<div id="fixed-content>
 My logo content and background
</div>

<div id="main-content">
Where my main content goes
</div>
```

What I need is for the main content to scroll up over the fixed content and the fixed content, I put the div as fixed that way I could get the effect of the fixed-content being scrolled over. I also have a fixed background to the fixed-content that works well but the actual elements within the fixed-content are still visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use z-index to your advantage there

Give the fixed div a lower z-index value than the content you want to cover it

So, for example:

```
#fixed-content {z-index: 1;}
#main-content {z-index: 99;}
```

Give that a try.

Comment: I tried that, although that doesn't seem to help I think since the item is fixed.

Comment: Give the main content a position of relative, that should work. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can add a div with `position: absolute` on the `position: fixed` div!

Which will move with the `position: fixed` (would be a child, of course).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, could you elaborate please.

Comment: I mean you can add a child element inside a fixed div, and use it! It will float inside the fixed div..

Comment: So I added a div inside the div fixed-content  and made it absolute and that didn't work, is that what you meant?

Comment: No, I don't think you understood me! When you're making the div absolute, you are making a relative div too and giving it some parameters too! So I just want you to add a child element inside the fixed div..